# Show that the function is $f(x,y)=\{\frac{\sqrt{x+2}}{y^2} ;(x,y)\neq(0,0)$, otherwise zero continuous at $(0,0)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

$$f(x,y)=\{\frac{\sqrt{x+2}}{y^2} ;(x,y)\neq(0,0)$$

$$f(x,y)=\{0; (x,y) =(0,0)$$

Prove that the function is continuous at (0,0).

I know that the limit of $$\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)}\frac{\sqrt{x+2}}{y^2} =...=0$$

I just don't know what to do in those three dots.... I tried polar coordinates and got nowhere since:

$$\lim_{r\rightarrow 0}\frac{\sqrt{r \cos \phi + 2}}{r^2\sin^2\phi} = ?$$

Comment: $ f(1, 0) = ? $

Comment: As defined the function is clearly divergent at $(0,0)$

Answer (score 1):

If we approach the point $(0,0)$ by the curve $(0,t)$ then the limit of $f(0,t)$ when t goes to $0$ is obiously $0$. On the other hand, if we approach the point $(0,0)$ by the curve $(t^4,t)$ then the limit of $f(t^4,t)$ when t goes to $0$ is $+\infty$. That implies that $f$ is not continuous at $(0,0)$.